# Regex, get some match from the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text like this:

> Some guy writes: some content.

or

> Some guy said: some content.

and i want to get all content from 'writes' to the end.

It is looking simple: `(said | writes):. *`

But. My text example can looks like this:

> Some guy writes: blablabla, said: some content

Here i want to get only 'said: some content'.
But my regex geting all content from 'writes' to the end.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Comment: @SibeeshVenu: it is there, and marked as code. (Although there is a space at the end that shouldn't be.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepend the regex you have with `^.*` and *capture* it:

```
^.*((?:said|writes):.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CCTcFN/1)

The initial `.*` will grab the whole line (or string if DOTALL modifier is used) and will backtrack to accommodate for `said:` or `writes:` that are *the last* on the string/line.

The non-capturing group in `(?:said|writes)` is used for grouping only purposes, so that there is only  one capturing group with ID = 1.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string/line anchor (depends on the modifiers used)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars *as many as possible* (as `*` is a *greedy quantifier*)  (other than line break symbols if DOTALL modifier is not used)
- `((?:said|writes):.*)` -  Group 1 capturing:

  - `(?:said|writes)` - either `said` or `writes` char sequences
  - `:` - a colon
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars (other than line break symbols if DOTALL modifier is not used) up to the end of line/string.

Comment: i don't think you need all the `^.*` see my answer

Comment: and your capture group is "unusual" the least. other than that, always good answers from you

Comment: @Fallenhero: *Here i want to get only 'said: some content'.* It was not me who set such requirements.

Comment: it is looks like right answer, but how i can get only `\1` substitution in JavaScript?

Comment: oh, sorry, i see code example on regex101.com. Thank you guys)

Comment: Yes, there are code examples in the *code generator* section. The `$1` is the backreference you need. In JS, the replacement backreference syntax is `$` + the Group ID.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think without defining what the string is splitting by you could possibly do it with RegExp. You really should solidify the pattern for your string and enforce it's use, but here is a programmatic way to parse your strings.

```js
const writes = 'Some guy writes: some content.'
const said = 'Some guy said: some content.'
const blah = 'Some guy writes: blablabla, said: some content'

function objectifyString(str) {
  const reg = /(said|writes):/
  const index = str.search(reg) || 0
  const parts = str.substring(index).split(reg).filter(item => item.length)
  const obj = {}
  const ll = parts.length
  let ii = 0
  
  for (; ii < ll; ii+=2) {
    obj[parts[ii]] = (parts[ii+1]).trim()
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(
  objectifyString(blah)
)
console.log(
  [writes, said, blah].map(objectifyString)
)
```

Comment: My text can be split not only by a comma, it can be space, or any other symbols

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex : `^.*(\b\w+:.*)$`

The regex captures a group with pattern `"<word>:<some content>$"`

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/5FsGwR/1)

Answer (score 1):

here is your answer :

```
var text = "Some guy writes: blablabla, said: some content";

var output = /.*\s(\w+:.*)/.exec(text);
// output[1] contains your answer
```